# How do I execute an insert query with an unknown number of parameters in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Let's suppose I have all of these already provided:

- The name of a table
- An array containing the names of the columns in the table
- A corresponding array containing the values I want to insert into the table, as well as the types of those values.

I would normally do a query like this

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($mysqli);
if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, 'INSERT INTO `Table` (columns) VALUES (values) ')) {
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, /* types */, /* values */);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

But I can't figure out how to make this more general so that I can feed in my column names, values, and types, and execute the query.

What's the best way to do this? I would prefer to not have to install a library for this purpose.

Comment: I've had success using an associative array for parameters - the keys are the column names and the values are, uh, the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well for the columns names you could just do an `implode` of the column array and `sprintf` it into your query.

For the types you can also `implode` them into strings and feed them into `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`.

For values you have do to some tricky manipulations (using [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)):

```
$args = array(); // to be put into call_user_func_array

$args[] =& $stmt; // because the statement HAS TO be by reference.
$args[] = implode("", $types);

foreach($values as $value){
    $args[] = $value;
}

call_user_func_array("mysqli_stmt_bind_param", $args);
```

Comment: I tried that, but I got an error saying that `bind_param` received a value as the second parameter when it expected a reference.

Comment: @PeterOlson ahhh sorry, I forgot the `&` try it now :-)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I should have asked this question hours ago. I do have one correction though, it's not the `$stmt` that has to be a reference, it's the `$value`.

Comment: @PeterOlson so it is `$args[] =& $value`?